# Django login() doesn't persist after HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, authentication

I have custom Django login forms that, since upgrading from `Django 1.8` to `2.2`, no longer keep user logged in after `HttpResponseRedirect`. Here's is a generalized sample of the code:

```
@render_with('users/login.html')
def login_view(request, campaign_id=None):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            # Login user
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/redirect-user/')
```

I know that `login()` is working properly because if I use `render` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`, the user is logged in. However, I want to redirect the user to a different view after login. What is the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**

It appears that the culprit is my custom authenticate backend `EmailOrUsernameModelBackend`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

***settings.py***

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
  'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
  'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
  'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
  'social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
  'users.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

***__init__.py***

```
class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(object):

    supports_object_permissions = False
    supports_anonymous_user = False
    supports_inactive_user = False

    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        if '@' in email:
            kwargs = {'email': email.lower() }
        else:
            kwargs = {'username__iexact': email.lower() }
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Also, if I change the code and logout/login again to test, it works the 1st test and fails on subsequent tests with the same user.

Comment: Apologies for my English.

When you create a login, it will add a token that will be passed to the user in the function **render (request** ..., when you redirect the user, that token was not passed).
You can try pass this request in redirect function, but never try it, but why it doesn't work I think that's it.For test, you can try use a django redirect function. Test and let me know, I'll leave as a comment for now. Say more after you did, and let's try to work it out together.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. [Redirect is also the right way to do it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in). Be sure `/redirect-user/` view is right. This is [how I code loginviews and works right](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/django-aula/blob/master/aula/apps/usuaris/views.py#L274)

Comment: Do you have any other middleware that might be causing issues?

Comment: The `/redirect-user/` view is not the problem because I've also tried redirecting to `/` and seen the same issue. I think @Sayse might be onto something - I will update the question with middleware info. Also, if I change the code and logout/login again to test, it works the 1st test and fails on subsequent tests with the same user.

Comment: Because @Sayse has a crystal ball :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Sayse's suggestion about middleware/backends causing the issue. Removing `'users.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend'` fixed the issue in the question above, but consequently broke my login after a new user registers. In order to get both login and registration working, I switched the other of `EmailOrUsernameModelBackend` and `ModelBackend`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
  'users.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
)
```

Per Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends):

> The order of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS matters, so if the same username
>   and password is valid in multiple backends, Django will stop
>   processing at the first positive match.

I am still not sure what is wrong with the `EmailOrUsernameModelBackend` causing it to break my login, but this did fix the issue. If anybody has a better fix for the root cause (ie what is wrong with this backend), I will accept as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but reordering the backends in settings did not help.

`login(request, user)` can take a third argument, the backend to use, e.g.

```
backend = `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(request, user, backend)
```

If you remove `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` from settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, inside `django/contrib/auth/__init__.py -> get_user` is:

```
        if backend_path in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:
            ...
        else:
            return None
```

So if you specify the backend, but its not in your `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, your user will never authenticate.